# Running my Node app with Forever does not log any output

Tags: linux, node.js, centos

I am running my node project using Forever on a Amazon CentOS EC2 instance using the following command:

```
forever start -o /home/ec2-user/logs/www.log -e /home/ec2-user/logs/www.err app.js
```

My application runs properly but there are no www.log or www.err files created in the logs directory.  I tried manually creating these files and setting chmod 777, and still, there is no data logged to these files.  I am certain that there should be data logging; I am running the same project in a similar environment and everything is logging OK.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a breaking change in one of the more recent node releases.  Someone recently filed a related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/193

Unfortunately Forever seems to output child process error messages to stdout, so redirecting stderr to a file doesn't work.  A temporary workaround would be to use an older version of node.  Hopefully a fix will be out soon.